# File object converts to fakepath when saving inside an object

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've a image input in my webpage and input's output (File object) is saved inside the Question class. `questionArr` is a array of Question objects

```
  let questionsArr = []; // Array of Question

  class Question {
    constructor(id) {
      this.id = id;
      this.image = false;
    }
  }
```

when the input value of image input changes, following function calls.

```
  const handleImages = evt => {
    let id = evt.target.id; // quizCoverImg or a integer (0,1,...)
    const file = evt.target.files[0];

    if (file && file.type.startsWith("image/")) {
      if (id == "quizCoverImg") {
        coverImage = file; // declared in top of the code
        // console.log(coverImage) => File {name: "cat.png", lastModified ...}
        // Returns a file object, which is correct
      } else {
        questionsArr[id].image = file;
        // console.log(questionsArr[id].image) => File {name: "cat.png", lastModified ...}
        // Returns a file object, which is correct
      }
    }
  };
```

To this point everything works fine. Problem arise when I use above variables somewhere eles

```
const somewhereElse = () => {
    console.log(coverImage); // File {name: "cat.png", lastModified ...} ✔
    console.log(typeof coverImage); // object ✔
    console.log(questionsArr[0].image); // C:\fakepath\cat.jpg ❓ should return a file object as mentioned above
    console.log(typeof questionsArr[0].image); // string ❓
}
```

I know `FileReader()` exist, but I want to figure out why I'm getting two different outputs here.
Issue occurred in `svelte@3.22.2`

---

Edit 1: Places where questionArr used
This add Question to array

```
  const addQuestion = () => {
    const q = new Question(n);
    questionsArr = [...questionsArr, q]; // because I'm using svelte :)
    n++;
  };
```

Then used in above `handleImage()`

Comment: Could you show us each time you use the `questionsArr`?

Comment: @ChrisR done...

Answer (score 0):

The key difference is in the `toString()` method that affects what you are looking at. There is not much context to help debug the details of exactly how you are running this and how you are inspecting the values.

When you have selected a file in a form file input, the browser converts the path to a "fakepath" so that while the script can access the selected file, it cannot learn about the user's directory structure.  The filename/path is a reasonable default `toString` result when trying to inspect/print the file object.